# Rewriting function with fopen and fscanf from C to assembly

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86

I wrote function in C that does work fine for me, but I need to write the same function in assembly. I generated assembly code of this function using `gcc -S rrd.c and I need some help in implementing it in asm. I'm using Linux, x86 assembly.

My C function:

```
double rrd (double a)
{

FILE *f=fopen("inital.txt","r");

    if(f==NULL)
        return 1;

    double first, second;

    do
    {
        fscanf(f, "%lf", &first);
        fscanf(f, "%lf", &second);
    }
    while(a >= first);

    close(f);
    return second;
}
```

This is what I get:
http://pastebin.com/zyEBgTEC

And this is what I have so far:

```
.data
mode:
    .string "r"
file:
    .string "inital.txt"
format:
    .string "%lf"
value:
    .space 8
first:
    .space 8
second:
    .space 8
pointer:
    .space 8
.text
.global re
re: 
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    fldl    8(%ebp)
    fstpl   value

    pushl   $mode
    pushl   $file
    call    fopen
    movl    %eax, pointer
    cmpl    $0, pointer
jne loop

jmp end

loop:
    leal    16(%esp), %edx
    pushl   %edx
    pushl   $format
    pushl   pointer
    call    __isoc99_fscanf

    leal    24(%esp), %edx
    pushl   %edx
    pushl   $format
    pushl   pointer
    call    __isoc99_fscanf

    fldl    16(%esp)
    fldl    32(%esp)

    pushl   pointer
    call    close

end:
leave
ret
```

Result after fldl instructions:

```
st0            -2.3534389814351579410727679528547297e-185   (raw 0xbd99ccccd5ffff9ac000)
st1            -1.9968719781118224876337308160145767    (raw 0xbfffff99804025016800)
```

My problem is that I don't exactly know where are the results of fscanf instructions and I don't know why there are those leal instructions.

Could anyone help me to rewrite this function?

Comment: I realized that second fldl should be with my 'value' and that my results are in 16(%esp) and 24(%esp), but I don't know why it read value from file not corectly.

Comment: If you solved it, you could post the answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it should look like this:

```
wiecej:
        leal    pierwsza, %edx
        pushl   %edx
        pushl   $format
        pushl   wskaznik    
        call    __isoc99_fscanf

        leal    druga, %edx
        pushl   %edx
        pushl   $format
        pushl   wskaznik
        call    __isoc99_fscanf

        fldl    pierwsza
        fldl    b
        fucomip %st(1), %st
        fstp    %st(0)
        setae   %al
        testb   %al, %al
    jne wiecej
        fldl    druga
```